# Can GDAL run XML Composition File for GeoPDF from command line?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

The documentation page for PDF via GDAL includes the description for using an XML Composition File:
https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html#creation-of-pdf-file-from-a-xml-composition-file-gdal-3-0

But, the description only gives examples of the XML Composition file being used from C++ or Python code.

Is it possible to use the XML Composition file directly from GDAL commands on the command line?